# Why can atmospheric re-entry heat up the air into plasma?

Tags: orbital-motion, atmospheric-science, earth, space

[image]

The adiabatic processes of re-entering earth from a spaceship, creates intense heat. Heat in the range of 1700-2000 degrees Celsius.

I've read the the temperature in the air molecules generate a very hot plasma which glows in the red-orange spectrum.

But Di-nitrogen should only turn plasma 10.000 + degrees Celsius.

How is this possible? I'm guessing the 1700-2000 temperature is only at the spacecraft, while only the surrounding air are reaching these plasma temperatures. But I can't find sources.

Comment: Okay I'm just finding this on wiki: "the air in the shock layer is both ionized and dissociated". So these plasma-temperatures are generated from the constructive interference of the pressure wave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question. By re-entering atmosphere spaceship transfers it's kinetic energy to impacting air molecules, thus molecules starts to move at a spaceship speed too. Knowing average molecules speed (which would be an aircraft speed) we can calculate shock-wave zone gas temperature :
$$ T={m{\overline {v^{2}}} \over 3k_{B}} $$
Typical re-entry speed of Space Shuttle is about $7823 \,\text{m/s}$, this gives shock zone temperature $\approx 68'000 \,\,\text{Celsius}$,-
seems more than enough to heat Nitrogen into a plasma.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you put some words on why the spacecraft isn't 68.000 degrees Celsius?

Comment: Spacecrafts are protected with a heat shield composed of layers from special materials dissipating heat received. Also according to this decent answer in [space.stackexchange](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/15060/34903) there's an ablative cooling mechanism in action and besides at these altitudes air density is very small, so heat is transferred from plasma to spacecraft at low rates.

Comment: Good reference, the simulations referenced are close to your "back on the envelope" calcualtion.  Thank you